# Pre-define list of variables to set them in bulk

Tags: syntax

I understand this is likely tremendously simple, but I cannot work out how to do the following:

```
vars = {b,c} *define variables*
vars = {1,2} *set them*
```

Then I would like `b` to output to 1 and `c` to output to 2. I thought the answer would lie somewhere in replacing one of the two `=`'s with `:=` or `->` or `:->` but no luck.

Comment: `{b,c}={1,2}` works. Is this acceptable?

Comment: @Manuel--Moe--G That is certainly the simplest functional answer. But, just for exposition, I would prefer to pre-define the variables and then set them in a manner similar to my code snippet. As for why, suppose I have a long list of variables and I want to change the 97th. With your method, I have to find the 97th element on the RHS and change it. With my system, I can simply leave the original ones and, supposing I know that the name of the 97th element is `zz`, I can reset `zz=3`.

Comment: `vars = {b, c}
vals = {1, 2}
vars = vars /. Thread[vars -> vals]`?

Comment: I think it is a duplicate, is that what you need? `Set[a, x_] ^:= {b, c} = x`?

Comment: Why do you want to do things this way? The context here is important, since this is sort of a weird way to go about doing things in *Mathematica*.

Comment: @Kuba Yes, that does it. Thank you. Can you point me to a question that explains that syntax?

Comment: @march See my edited comment above. If you think I'm misguided in my reasoning, I'm keen to hear why.

Comment: sorry to say, but 100 named variables is always going to be clunky in MMA. A single list of 100 elements or a single identifier used as such a[1]=17, a[2]=13, ... a[100]=42 will be less clunky. Sample code for context would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Manuel--Moe--G I have a bunch of variables and they can be grouped into categories. So I would like to define them into their categories (for exposition) and then set the values for the category. Think `colors = {r,g,b}`, `colors = {1,2,3}`. I think this is more readable to people unfamiliar with Mathematica (the person I am writing it for is unfamiliar with Mathematica).

Comment: If I am making a self-documenting data structure in MMA, I am more likely to do `{r->1,g->2,b->3}` or `{"r"->1,"g"->2,"b"->3}`

Comment: @Shane. In that case, you might want to look into the `Association` data structure. That seems like a natural fit here, and the syntax is relatively transparent.

Comment: Or to generalize @march's comment: look at `Dataset`.

Comment: Ok, I've failed to find it and I don't have much more time now.

Comment: @Kuba That's fine. I think you're correct that an association is probably the way to go in any case. Thanks!